# Creating an activity to provide multiple options to select

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new Xamarin android development. Please excuse if the question sounds simple. I am creating a form where I need to provide user with option to select multiple option, kind of like checkbox group. The number of option could be bigger like 10-20. I am not which control or layout to use so that it's easy for the user to read and select the options. I tried layout with linear and vertical options but that doesn't look nice. Also how can create those options programmatically based on some data source. Please suggest me best way to design this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is snippet in my axml

I've tried using the LinearLayout and used the checkbox control

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"          
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/blogging"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Blog"/>
  <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/game"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
     android:text="Game" />
```

Comment: Can you visually show me what are you trying to achieve as your question is confusing

Comment: @G.hakim thanks for responding. It's basically a design questions. I've to design a user interface where user can select multiple options. The number of options can be  large like 15-20 and make take lot of space on the screen. I added multiple check boxes in a LinearLayout.  And it doesn't look good.I am looking for what other options do I have? Is there in built control/tool in the xamarin tool kit. Any pointer to sample codebse would be appreciated.

Something like the settings page in iOS/android app where use see a list of options and he/she can turn on/off.

Comment: Xamarin.Android is just Native Android with C# code behind (instead of java) it only has things that are available in Native Android, I am unaware of any such control that you are talking about!

Comment: @G.hakim Thanks for replying. I think I found what I was looking for. It's called the switch control. I am using that to create settings like page. Here is sample code snippet for someone else looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Found what I was looking for. It's called the Switch tool. So to provide settings page like options, I'll use this instead of checkboxes
<Switch
   android:id="@+id/blogging"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch"
   android:hint="Blog"
  />
<Switch
   android:id="@+id/game"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch"             
   android:text="Game" />
```

Comment: please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Sure @LeonLu-MSFT . It doesn't let me vote for my answer :)